# "Patch failed" in EMNLP Style Template

Tags: errors, etoolbox

I was trying to use the LaTeX files for the EMNLP 2019 conference (download link can be found [here](https://www.emnlp-ijcnlp2019.org/calls/papers#formatting-requirements)), but when I try to compile the provided example `.tex` file, it doesn't work and I get the following error for file `emnlp-ijcnlp-2019.sty`:

```
Line 455: patch failed ...x}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}
```

Interestingly, the [Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/emnlp2019-templates/jmjnzffkknqc) using the identical `.sty` file works just fine, so I assume this is not an issue in the `.sty` file, but rather an issue with my local environment.

In case this is relevant, I am using `pdflatex` on Windows 10.

**What may cause this error message to appear, and how can I fix it?** Is it possible to fix this problem without changing the `.sty` file?

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I've looked up the corresponding line (and the two lines above), which read:

```
% DK/IV: Workaround for annoying hyperref pagewrap bug 
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{\box\@outputbox}{\unvbox\@outputbox}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}
```

A quick search revealed [this comment](https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/19#issuecomment-319483975) from which the lines above seem to be taken.

I have the `etoolbox` package installed and I've also tried the following MWE instead of the example `.tex` file, which gives the same error:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{emnlp-ijcnlp-2019}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a MWE for the `.sty` file as I don't really understand its contents.

Comment: just delete the line `\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{\box\@outputbox}{\unvbox\@outputbox}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}` and you will get the intended result, since 2018 latex releases the original source already has unvbox so patch can not find box

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not allowed to modify the `.sty` file (according to conference rules), hence my question whether it is also possible to fix this problem without changing the file.

Comment: The conference rules were not expecting latex to change and break their style file, the style simply will not work with current latex so change your copy it will work the same way on anew latex as the unchanged class with the patch will work on an old one,  So you can still submit your article they don't need to "know" that you changed the local copy of the class.

Comment: I got the same problem when I compile the paper with the ACL2020 style file on my MacBook and Windows 10. [latex template link](http://acl2020.org/downloads/acl2020-templates.zip).
To solve it, I delete '\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}' in the last braces — no error message in both computers and overleaf.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your local copy of the package, just delete the line

```
\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{\box\@outputbox}{\unvbox\@outputbox}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}
```

and you will get the intended result, since 2018 latex releases the original source already has `\unvbox` so `\patchcmd` can not find the `\box` to replace.

The LaTeX sources document the change as:

```
% \changes{v1.4d}{2018/11/28}{Unbox \cs{@outputbox} to preserve boxing
```

In comments you mention that you are not allowed to change the package, but that rule was written to ensure you do not change the document design by editing the `.sty` file.

The conference rules were not expecting latex to change and break their file. The code simply will not work with current latex so change your copy: it will work the same way on anew latex as the unchanged file with the patch will work on an old one.

So you can still submit your article they don't need to "know" that you changed the local copy of the package, although you could report it to them referencing this answer.

Comment: Note that this still holds for EMNLP 2020

Comment: @drevicko could you report it to them? if they change `\errmessage` to `\wlog` it will just log that the patch failed in new releases, but still do the patch in old releases and will work the same way in either case.

Comment: [done](https://github.com/acl-org/acl-pub/issues/32)

Answer (score 3):

Because I do not have an Overleaf account please do the following test:

Add the line `\listfiles` as the first line to the file `emnlp2019.tex`:

```
%
% File emnlp2019.tex
%
%% Based on the style files for ACL 2019, which were
%% Based on the style files for EMNLP 2018, which were
%% Based on the style files for ACL 2018, which were
%% Based on the style files for ACL-2015, with some improvements
%%  taken from the NAACL-2016 style
%% Based on the style files for ACL-2014, which were, in turn,
%% based on ACL-2013, ACL-2012, ACL-2011, ACL-2010, ACL-IJCNLP-2009,
%% EACL-2009, IJCNLP-2008...
%% Based on the style files for EACL 2006 by 
%%e.agirre@ehu.es or Sergi.Balari@uab.es
%% and that of ACL 08 by Joakim Nivre and Noah Smith

\listfiles % <====================================================
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{emnlp-ijcnlp-2019}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
...
```

Now compile three times on Overleaf and check the resulting log file `emnlp2019.log` at the end for a list of used packages and versions. I'm very sure you will find an older version of `hyperref` listed ...

Please add this list to your question.

Then compile the same file `emnlp2019.tex` with the added `\listfile` on your computer. Once again check the resulting log file and search for the used version of `hyperref`. I'm sure it is newer ...

Please add the resulting list of used packages and versions to your question too!

The reason for my guess is the following code in the used `sty` file:

```
% DK/IV: Workaround for annoying hyperref pagewrap bug 
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{\box\@outputbox}{\unvbox\@outputbox}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}
```

As you can see in the comment above the used `\patchcmd` there was a bug in an older version of `hyperref` (which one is not named, that would be really helpful!). The used patch wants to correct is, but on your current computer system the patch failed, because

- command `\@combinedblfloats` can not be found or
- command `\box\@outputbox` can not be found to be changed to `\unvbox\@outputbox`

For a quick test do the following:

1. create a new directory.
2. copy all files from the zip file in your given link into that directory.
3. Add `\listfiles` to the template Tex file `emnlp2019.tex`
4. comment on the shown lines above in the file `emnlp-ijcnlp-2019.sty` and
5. recompile the file `emnlp2019.tex`

**Error gone?** Okay, the patch seems to be no longer needed.

**Error still there?** Contact the maintainer of the zip file and report the bug you found.

Comment: the latex format has `% \changes{v1.4d}{2018/11/28}{Unbox \cs{@outputbox} to preserve boxing`  so in recent formats that patch will fail as it has already been applied essentially.

Comment: Your guess is correct: overleaf uses `2017/03/14 v6.85a` whereas the version on my computer is `2018/11/30 v6.88e`. After removing the patch, everything works fine.

Comment: `\@combinedblfloats` (and the change that makes the patch fail) are not in the files listed by `\listfiles` it is a change in the latex format.