# patch failed error for ACL 2020 sty file in overleaf pro

Tags: errors, packages

How should I fix this tex/overleaf error?

[image]

It pertains to the following piece of code below in acl2020.sty file.

```
% DK/IV: Workaround for annoying hyperref pagewrap bug 
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{\box\@outputbox}{\unvbox\@outputbox}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}
```

You can download the ACL overleaf package here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acl-2020-proceedings-template/zsrkcwjptpcd

Comment: Probably similar to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487751